# C# applicationHost.config not found but exists

Tags: c#, filesystems, filenotfoundexception

I'm getting a strange error when accessing applicationsHost.config.
I've run VisualStudio in administrator mode and trying to access

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
```

but I get exception FileNotFound while file exists.

```
var file = @"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config";
var fileExist = System.IO.File.Exists(file); //it always returns false
var fi=System.IO.File.OpenRead(file);  //Throws FileNotFound exception
```

I've tested on VS2013 and VS2017 on Windows 10.
I don't get any error related to permission and even I've added Everyone to the folder to be sure it's related to that.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it's related 'File System Redirection' on Windows 8.1 onward.
So %windir%\System32 would be redirected to %windir%\SysWOW64
Thanks to @NGambit
I had to change config type to x64 to be able to access applicationhost.config

Answer (score 0):

if using net framework app, change target platform to x64 in project properties